# Nested apply function: variable confusion

Tags: r, apply

I have a bit of code which uses a nested `apply` function.  It is a bit unusual, because it uses a list of functions which it then feeds into the `FUN` argument of the inner `vapply`.

Here is the code line:

```
J <- sapply(X = J.int, FUN = vapply, X = t.vec, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
```

where `J.int` is a list of functions generated by `approx.fun`.  As may be predicted, the code gets confused about argument `X`.  I have a solution, which I will post below, but it doesn't seem very elegant.  If anyone can create a function which is easily generalisable for all the `apply` functions, or suggest an alternative solution, I would like to see that answer.

For reproducibility, use:

```
J.lst <- list(data.frame(t = 0.5:9.5, J = rnorm(10, 5, 1)), data.frame(t = 0.5:9.5, J = rnorm(10, 6, 3)))
J.int <- lapply(J.lst, function(df) approxfun(df[, 1] + t.0, df[, 2], yleft = 0, yright = 0))
t.vec <- 1:10
t.0 <- 0
```

Comment: what is `t.0` in `approxfun(df[, 1] + t.0, df[, 2] ...` ?

Comment: Apologies.  Might as well be `0` for this.  Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution, referred to in the question, is to use:

```
applyntd <- function(appFUN = apply, Xntd, FUNntd, MARGINntd, FUN.VALUEntd, simplifyntd, USE.NAMESntd, ...){
  appFUN <- match.fun(appFUN)
  if(identical(appFUN, apply)) return(function(Xntd, MARGINntd, FUNntd, ...) apply(X = Xntd, MARGIN = MARGINntd, FUN = FUNntd, ...))
  if(identical(appFUN, lapply)) return(function(Xntd, FUNntd, ...) lapply(X = Xntd, FUN = FUNntd, ...))
  if(identical(appFUN, sapply)) return(function(Xntd, FUNntd, ..., simplifyntd = T, USE.NAMESntd = T) sapply(X = Xntd, FUN = FUNntd, ..., simplify = simplifyntd, USE.NAMES = USE.NAMESntd))
  if(identical(appFUN, vapply)) return(function(Xntd, FUNntd, FUN.VALUEntd, ..., USE.NAMESntd = T) vapply(X = Xntd, FUN = FUNntd, FUN.VALUE = FUN.VALUEntd, ..., USE.NAMES = USE.NAMESntd))
}
```

and then:

```
J <- sapply(X = J.int, FUN = applyntd(vapply), Xntd = t.vec, FUN.VALUEntd = numeric(1))
```

This works, but the `applyntd` function seems cumbersome.  Let me know if you have better/ more generalisable ideas.